# Не грузится блок ya-share2 через load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, share, ya-share2

Нужно реализовать следующее: при клике с главной на ссылку с новостью, новость должна открываться не на своей странице, а должен появляться всплывающий блок, куда загружалась бы информация с отдельной страницы новости с помощью функции jquery .load().

Проблема в том, что в всплывающий блок подгружается всё необходимое, кроме содержимого блока «Поделиться». Ссылки на соцсети не грузятся.

Нужно сделать так, чтобы в всплывающем блоке появлялся блок соцсетей "Поделиться", при клике на которые мы делились бы ссылкой не той страницы, на которой мы находимся (не главной), а той страницы с новостью, с которой мы берем информацию.

На отдельной странице с новостью ссылки блока "Поделиться" работают как надо.

Что тут можно предпринять?

Comment: Будет проще понять задачу и помочь вам, если вы приложите минимальный пример кода.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Столкнулся с подобной проблемой. Решение: [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/669740/15872)

Вместо **"// ваш код"** вставляем **"Ya.share2('ya-share', { // ну и всё остальное"**.

Должно сработать.